# What is the answer of this question "If it's OK by you, I _____________ early today." and why?

Tags: modal-verbs, present-continuous

> If it's ok by you , I_____________early today
>
> a. leave
>
> b. will leave
>
> c. am leaving
>
> d. will be leave

If I were to answer I would pick **"will leave"** but I'm confused because I feel that it can be "am leaving" as well.

Comment: b and c are both good. a is grammatical, but not idiomatic except in particular circumstances. No idea what you question setter wanted.

Comment: "Were it OK by you, I would leave early today" ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Could I make a suggestion that this is completely rephrased?

> If it's OK by you

Isn't really something a native speaker would say.

> If it's OK with you...

Is better.

> I will leave

or

> I am leaving

both of these work great, a and d are both grammatically incorrect.

Also, if you are asking your boss to leave early, saying it in this fashion may come across as rude, as it can seem like you are stating that you will be leaving early whether the person you are asking likes it or not, despite the first part of the sentence.

So, in conclusion, I would say,

> Would it be possible for me to leave early today?

With a please and a thank you.

HTH

Comment: I disagree with your first point. "OK by me" is a phrase I have heard for fifty years - it may be that it is dated now.

Comment: And there is nothing in the question to warrant the assumption that this is to the boss: it might equally be to a colleague at the same level, in which case the informality is fine.

Comment: `OK by me` is a phrase that I'm quite comfortable with, however, `if that's OK by you` doesn't sound natural to me, at least not as natural as `if that's OK with you`.

Comment: I think "okay **by** you/me" and "fine **by** you/me" would be fine when used in any place where a person can use informal language comfortably. I've heard this expression used  by Canadians, Americans and Brits, so I'll assume it is fairly common and used most places English is spoken. The problem the OP had was with tense. I'd warn new English speakers to speak a little more formally until they know when to use any colloquialisms, because it could sound like a barb if used incorrectly.

Comment: I think 'fine by you/me' sounds better than 'OK by you/me'. I still feel uncomfortable for some reason saying 'if that's OK with you' when I'm trying to keep my tone cordial in a conversation though, I feel as though it's more confrontational than just asking. Maybe that's just my British instinct though.

Answer (score 0):

"If it's ok by you," simply makes it a question; whatever comes after should stand on its own as a statement.

So I would go for "I will leave early today" as the best option, or even more natural sounding would be "I'm going to leave early today". "I am leaving early today" also sounds fine.

"I leave early today" is grammatical but sounds very unnatural, and "I will be leave early today" is simply wrong.